# Difference between list comprehension and loops

Tags: python, loops, list-comprehension

```
mag=[]
for i in nbn:
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        if i%j==0:
            mag.append(j)
```

It was a part of my code at the beginning, then for optimizing my code, I replaced it with another list comprehension, but it gives me a different output.

```
mag=[i for i in numbers_before_n  for j in range(1,i+1) if i%j==0]
```

What is the difference between these two types of loops?

Comment: In the for loop you are adding `j` to the `mag` list but in the list comprehension you are saving `i` to `mag` list.

Answer (score 3):

In your case list comprehension returns `i` but you want `j`:

```
mag=[j for i in numbers_before_n  for j in range(1,i+1) if i%j==0]
```